# How to update a Google doc by preserving the document properties and styling using Google drive api?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a use case where I have to update a google doc having some user defined styling and dropdowns. When I update the doc with the content using the Google drive api, both the user-defined styling and dropdowns are not applied.

I am using the below code to update the document.

```
file = drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body=file_metadata)
```

But the above code updates the document without preserving the existing user-defined styles and dropdowns.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I update the doc with the content using the Google drive api, both the user-defined styling and dropdowns are not applied.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the content of an html file into the Google doc using the Google drive API update method. But the document styling and custom dropdown are not retained after the insert. I want to retain these properties after the update.

Comment: If you can elaborate your question further, share your working code and provide some examples/dummy documents, it would be really helpful to replicate your concern.